# jQuery if this is disabled - not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to check whether a selector is disabled on click.

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary sendOrderToSage" data-id="97" disabled="disabled">Send To Sage</a>
```

My current code, that isn't working, is:

```
$('.sendOrderToSage').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).is(':disabled') == true){
        return false;
    }
 /* Continue function */
 });
```

I have also attempted `$('.sendOrderToSage:not(:disabled)').....` but that yeilds the same result as the above attempt.

Comment: Re "overly complicated": `$('.sendOrderToSage').on('click', function() { if (this.disabled) { return false; } /* continue function */ });`. There's no reason to use jQuery to check if it's disabled, and there's never any reason for `== true` in a condition.

Comment: Unfortunately, even that doesn't work T.J.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder... Please see http://jsfiddle.net/088a4c06/1/ That's a minimal approach and it's still not working.

Comment: MCVEs go **in** the question, not just linked. But actually, I'd just overlooked that you're misusing the `disabled` attribute; my answer explains what's going on and what to correctly do about it.

Comment: I've read your answer and realised the error I was making, I have corrected my coding mistake and learnt a valuable lesson. Thank you

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice the `a` earlier!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`disabled` attribute/property is valid for elements such as `input,select` etc.
In an anchor tag `disabled` is just another attribute. So if you want to get it, you need to use **[attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)**

```js
$('.sendOrderToSage').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($(this).attr('disabled') == 'disabled') {
    return false;
  }
  /* Continue function */
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary sendOrderToSage" data-id="97" disabled="disabled">Send To Sage</a>
```

## With `:disabled`

Here the return of `$(this).is(':disabled')` for a `<a>` will always be false because it is an invalid attribute for an anchor.

```js
$('.sendOrderToSage').on('click mousedown', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert($(this).is(':disabled'));
  if ($(this).attr('disabled') == 'disabled') {
    return false;
  }
  /* Continue function */
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary sendOrderToSage" data-id="97" disabled="disabled">This will always return false.</a><br/>
```

Comment: That has fixed it. I had attempted `attr('disabled') == true` but not `== 'disabled'`. It makes sense now!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ... The trouble is, it didn't work. Regardless of what was tried.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think you did not notice that the `$(this).is(':disabled')` always retunrs false. See this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rejithrkrishnan/y0n69fqc/3/)

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan: I just noticed that the OP's code is using `a`, which *cannot* be disabled.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes. I mentioned that in the answer only after I posted it initially. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that `a` elements [**can't be disabled**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fe-disabled). `disabled` is an invalid attribute for [`a` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element).

If you want to have an attribute on an `a` element that indicates that it should not be clickable, your only valid HTML option is to use a [`data-*` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) instead. Then you can "disable" it with:

```
$(".sendOrderToSage").attr("data-disabled", "Y");
```

and "enable" it with:

```
$(".sendOrderToSage").removeAttr("data-disabled");
```

and your click function becomes:

```
$('.sendOrderToSage').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($(this).attr('data-disabled')) {
    return false;
  }
  /* Continue function */
});
```

**Live Example**:

```js
$('.sendOrderToSage').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($(this).attr('data-disabled')) {
    alert("Click was stopped");
    return false;
  }
  /* Continue function */
});
$(document.body).on("click", "a.sendOrderToSage", function() {
  alert("Click was not stopped");
});
$("#togglebox").on("click", function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $(".sendOrderToSage").attr("data-disabled", "Y");
  } else {
    $(".sendOrderToSage").removeAttr("data-disabled");
  }
});
```

```html
<div>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="togglebox" checked>Disable the link
  </label>
</div>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary sendOrderToSage" data-id="97" data-disabled="disabled">Send To Sage</a>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```